# SpringBootTest does not pick TestConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

I upgraded to Spring Boot 2.1 and one test started failing:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(
     webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
     classes = [CacheService::class]
 )
 @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
 class CacheIntegrationTest {

    // Tests

    @EnableCaching
    @TestConfiguration
    class CacheTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        fun cacheManager(): CacheManager = CaffeineCacheManager()
    }
}
```

This configuration does not work unless I explicitly add CacheTestConfiguration to the classes array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to do that either via @Import(CacheTestConfiguration .class) or @ContextConfiguration(CacheTestConfiguration.class) on your test class and tell us  what you get?

Comment: @TinyOS works with @ Import but still is not as nice as it was before